# How to retrieve the value of a cell that is occupied by a function and not just a number using .value

Tags: excel, vba, range, cells

What im trying to do is create a function that will allow me to look at a range and count which cells are occupied by a number.

After doing this I will sum up the first 30 numbers that can be seen rather than just the first 30 cells in the range. I do this by asking if it is greater than 0 which means that it is a number and not a blank space.

My Code looks like this

```
Function cum(days_cum As Double, col_number As Double) As Double
Dim count As Long, sum As Double, i As Integer, number As Double
count = 0
For i = 15 To 1050
    number = Cells(i, col_number).Value
    If number > 0 Then
        count = count + 1
        sum = sum + number
        If count <= days_cum Then
        cum = sum
    End If
    End If
Next i
End Function
```

The problem im having is that some cells are using a function in order to calculate that number.

Any suggestions on working around this and getting my vba to work with this????? Help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: have you tried using specialcells? see http://tduhameau.wordpress.com/tag/specialcells/

Comment: What's wrong with `cells.Value`?  That returns the result of the formula. `cells.Formula`  would return the formula.

Comment: For some reason it returns just 0, i went back and copied the values back into the space as values only and it still returned a 0. I have no clue why its doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple **UDF** that will sum the first 30 numbers in a range, excluding both blanks and cells containing formulas:

```
Public Function AddFirst30(RIN As Range) As Variant
    Dim Kount As Long, t As Variant, r As Range
    k = 0
    t = 0
    For Each r In RIN
        If r.Value <> "" And r.HasFormula = False Then
            t = t + r.Value
            k = k + 1
            If k = 30 Then GoTo success
        End If
    Next r
    AddFirst30 = "Not enough numbers present"
    Exit Function

success:
    AddFirst30 = t
End Function
```

**EDIT#1:**

To change the **UDF** so that formulas are **not** excluded, just remove the *.HasFormula* test:

```
Public Function AddFirst30(RIN As Range) As Variant
    Dim Kount As Long, t As Variant, r As Range
    k = 0
    t = 0
    For Each r In RIN
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            t = t + r.Value
            k = k + 1
            If k = 30 Then GoTo success
        End If
    Next r
    AddFirst30 = "Not enough numbers present"
    Exit Function

success:
    AddFirst30 = t
End Function
```

Comment: Im gonna try this on Tuesday when I get back in to work. Would it be the exact same if I wanted to lets say add the first 60 or 90. Would I just change the 30 part to whatever amount I desire to add in the specified range?

Comment: Thank you so much. Saved me alot of time. Ill comment back on tuesday and let you know how it goes. Wish I had the file on my now to try.

Comment: How do I make it if I want to add the ones that have formulas in them. I just want the raw number added.

Comment: Is there a way to also say that there is not enough numbers but the sum is this and there were only x amount of numbers?

Comment: Yeah just pulled out my laptop and switched a few things up. I answered my previous questions by tinkering.

Comment: @user3670418 What was the problem? I was thinking either `days_cum` evaluating to 0 or `col_number` pointing to a blank column.

Comment: Im not sure I tried to figure out and couldn't.  I just used his code and it worked.  My days_cum was the value I gave it to add up that many numbers like 30 or 60. All columns had numbers in them. The problem was with getting the value of a cell that was determined in the worksheet by a function.

Comment: Is there any way that I could only add up the numbers above 300 but only when its before the largest number in the range but after the largest number add up all values.